# How to remove one whole div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons in a div :

1. plus button
2. minus button

when I click plus button, I'm creating another same div by cloning it and it is working fine, but when I click on minus button, in the same way, I need to remove one whole div, here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var addMoreConditions = function(evt) {
    var $div = document.getElementById('query_area');
    var queryDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('search_criteria1');
    // $div.appendChild($div);
    $(".search_criteria1:last").clone().insertAfter("div.search_criteria1:last");
  };
});

var removeConditions = function(ev) {
  $('#query_area').remove($(ev).parent()[0]);
}
```

```css
.m-form__group {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
  <div class="search_criteria1 form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <select class="field_attr1 form-control m-input"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="condition_div1 form-control m-input">
        <option value="eq">=</option>
        <option value="neq">!=</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="text" class="fieldValue1 form-control m-input" />

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" onclick="addMoreConditions()">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="+">

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" style="padding-left:20px" onclick="removeConditions(this)">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="-">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: look at delegated events. You need to use delegated events since you are removing elements that were not there on document ready. Look for jQuery .on()

Comment: @LelioFaieta OP is using inline event handlers.  Delegation has nothing to do with their problem.

Comment: I don't see how `addMoreConditions()` is working as you state, as the function declaration is not in scope of where you're calling it.

Comment: @Archer i see, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove `$(document).ready` as you are using inline events. And inline handler expects function to be under `global` scope. In your example, then are under local scope of `$(document).ready`

While removing, you can use [**`.closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select respective element to be removed.

```js
var addMoreConditions = function(evt) {
  var $div = document.getElementById('query_area');
  var queryDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('search_criteria1');
  // $div.appendChild($div);
  $(".search_criteria1:last").clone().insertAfter("div.search_criteria1:last");
};
var removeConditions = function(ev) {
  $(ev).closest('.search_criteria1').remove();
}
```

```css
.m-form__group {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
  <div class="search_criteria1 form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <select class="field_attr1 form-control m-input"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="condition_div1 form-control m-input">
        <option value="eq">=</option>
        <option value="neq">!=</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="text" class="fieldValue1 form-control m-input" />

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" onclick="addMoreConditions()">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="+">

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" style="padding-left:20px" onclick="removeConditions(this)">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="-">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good timing... (y)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I was about to comment that for your answer :P

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="col-1 removeitem" style="padding-left:20px">
```

give some specific  class or id  id used one class

```
 $(document).on("click", ".removeitem", function (e) { 
    //user click on remove 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to go up to the parent element then remove it like :

```
$(ev).closest('.search_criteria1').remove();
```

**NOTE 1:** When you `clone` the div it will be cloned with the user inputs, means if the user typed `100` in the last input then you clicked the plus button, the value of the input in the new cloned `div` will be `100` too. if you want to init the `input/select` for the new instance you could use the cloned div `cloned_div` as variable and init them first then push them to the view.

**NOTE 2:** You don't need the `queryDiv` and `$div` variables in your code, just remove them.

```js
var addMoreConditions = function(evt) {
  var last_div = "div.search_criteria1:last";
  var cloned_div = $(last_div).clone();

  cloned_div.find('.fieldValue1').val("");
  cloned_div.find('select').val("");

  cloned_div.insertAfter(last_div);
};

var removeConditions = function(ev) {
  $(ev).closest('.search_criteria1').remove();
}

$('button').click(function() {
  $('.search_criteria1').each(function(index) {
    index++;

    console.log('Field Attribute ' + index + ' : ' + $('.field_attr1', this).val());
    console.log('Condition Value ' + index + ' : ' + $('.condition_div1', this).val());
    console.log('Field Value ' + index + ' : ' + $('.fieldValue1', this).val());
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
  })
})
```

```css
.m-form__group {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
  <div class="search_criteria1 form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <select class="field_attr1 form-control m-input"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <select class="condition_div1 form-control m-input">
        <option value="eq">=</option>
        <option value="neq">!=</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <input type="text" class="fieldValue1 form-control m-input" />

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" onclick="addMoreConditions(this)">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="+">

    </div>
    <div class="col-1" style="padding-left:20px" onclick="removeConditions(this)">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="btn3" value="-">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button">GET DATA</button>
```

Comment: if i added 3 rows(3 search criteria) , how can i get the entered data one by one ?

Comment: You need to loop through them, check my updated snippet

Comment: thanks much @Zak ,  i took that like this var d = $('.search_criteria1')[i];
        var selectedFieldName = $(d).find('.field_attr1').val(); is there any drawbacks for this method ?

Comment: You're welcome brother, no there's no drawbacks, you could use your method too.